# Alternate the background color of lines of text

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc-3

Our project calls for alternately shaded lines  (gray-white-gray-white ...) of texts of different lengths, viewed at different sizes, etc., for on-screen and print viewing.

I don't think alternating table rows or divs is a solution because the # of words on a line (or in a row/div/span) may change with font sizes and browser resizing.

Thanks very much
Stephen

Comment: This is not possible without markup in place such as table rows or divs. You could develop a javascript solution to add such markup and text wrap based on screen width. Good luck

Comment: Or you could just add an background image with alternating gray and white lines.

While this won't accommodate changing text sizes, modern browsers nowadays have since preferred zooming in and out instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go, [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xeH25/).

Set a line-height on the font, then set a background-size to exactly twice that height. Put a linear gradient on the background with a 50% hard color stop, and set it to repeat.

The jsFiddle is just a quick thing I threw together to display this in Webkit browsers. You'll need to add in vendor specific code for all other browsers, of course.

```
p {
    line-height: 16px;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(50%, lightgray), color-stop(51%, white));
    background-size: 100% 32px;
}​
```

Comment: Despite the question being worded bad, this is a clever solution. +1 for nice problem solving/solution.

Comment: thanks.That was my first question, so sorry I worded it badly.

Comment: @one800higgins Thanks very much for the answer and sorry I didn't accept the answer quickly enough: I posted just before bed. Hadn't realized things moved so quickly here!